# Spark Datasets - Self Join Issue 3

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark-sql

I am getting error when I use self join in Spark SQL. Self inner-join on the dataSelfJoinTable- dataset column friends condition is working, but not with the data -dataset column friends condition in Spark Java.

```
 dataSelfJoinTable.alias("temp1")
            .join(data.alias("temp2"),
            data.col("friends")
            .equalTo("lalit")
            .and(dataSelfJoinTable.col("friends").
             equalTo("abhi"))
            ,"inner");
```